# How to boost::serialize pointers and reference?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I need serialize a class with fields: int, pointer to int, array, class object, pointer to class object, reference to class object, pointer to class object with virtual parent.

I tried to implement it. I managed to do for int and array. But I can not deal with pointers and references

```
class B() {};

class Person
{
 public:
int age; // work
    int *ageptr = &age; // not work
std::vector<int> favoriteNumbers; //work

    B b; // not work
    B *bptr = &b; // not work
    B &bref = b; // not work

Person();
~Person();

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(age);
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(ageptr); // error
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b); // error
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(bptr); // error
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(bref); // error
        ar &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(favoriteNumbers);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, since the references and pointers refer to member variables, they do not need to be serialized/deserialized. The constructor already set these members to correct values.

With regards to serializing pointers read Pointers section of [serialization tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

You cannot deserialize references in general, though, because they are aliases to other objects and they cannot be reassigned to refer to another object. Also, taking address and `sizeof` of a reference returns those of the object being referred. I would also [recommend against using reference members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54929207/412080) at all.